# JavaScript/TypeScript - Object assign only available properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

Following usecase: Lets assume I have an object with following properties:

```
const objOne = {
  car: 'ford',
  location: 'Munich',
  driver: 'John'
}
```

and a second Obj that only has some of the first Obj's properties:

```
const objTwo = {
  car: 'BMW',
  driver: 'Marta'
}
```

Is there a way to **assign** the properties from the second obj to the first obj without loosing the properties from the first obj. In this case `location: 'Munich'`. I know for a fact there is a method like `Object.assign` but this method completely copies the targeted obj, which I obviously don't want to.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: In matter of fact this is what [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) will do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly the behaviour of [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

```js
const objOne = {
  car: 'ford',
  location: 'Munich',
  driver: 'John'
}
        
const  objTwo = {
  car: 'BMW',
  driver: 'Marta'
}

console.log(objOne);
console.log(objTwo);

Object.assign(objOne, objTwo);
console.log('--assign--');
console.log(objOne);
```

Comment: Oh I messed up, thanks for the clearification. I really thought that the first objs. gets completely overwritten by the second one....